# Too many select lists polluting my controller actions

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, select, refactoring

I have an ASP.Net MVC application and some of the controller actions have about 10 select lists (others have more).  Currently my code looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int carId)
{
    CreateCar model = new CreateCar();

    model.Makes = Helper.Makes();
    model.Models = Helper.Models();
    model.Colors = Helper.Colors();
    model.EngineSizes = Helper.EngineSizes();
    model.Materials = Helper.Materials();
    model.FuelTypes = Helper.FuelTypes();
    model.WheelSizes = Helper.WheelSizes();
    model.BodyTypes = Helper.BodyTypes();
    //more select lists below this

    return View(model)
}
```

In my views i setup select lists like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x, Model.Makes)
```

I have code that looks like this in a number of actions and i feel there is a better way of doing this so my actions are not polluted with these select lists.

The only option i can think of to get around this is to actullly call the Helper class in the views e.g.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x, Helper.Makes())
```

Is this approach considered bad practice and are there any other approaches to deal wi this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, yes, it's bad practice to do things like that in your view. The controller is responsible for wiring everything up, so your code should go there. Now, it depends a lot on what your `Helper` class is doing. If the select lists are just generated via some bit of code, it's probably not that bad for that to happen in the view, but what you don't want to be doing is issuing database queries while the view is being rendered. If your helper is interacting with a database, then keep it in the controller.

That said, what is the real issue here? Sure that's a lot of select lists, but I wouldn't go so far as to say it's "polluting" your action. It's very clear what your doing. The action is responsible for creating the model for your view, and that's what it's doing. Just because there may be a lot of lines in your code, doesn't necessarily mean it's "bad" or "wrong".

However, if you're repeating this in a lot of places, I would recommend factoring it out into a private or protected method on your controller. For example:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int carId)
{
    ...

    PopulateSelectLists(model);
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Foo model, int carId)
{
    ...

    PopulateSelectLists(model);
    return View(model);
}

private void PopulateSelectLists(Foo model)
{
    model.Makes = Helper.Makes();
    model.Models = Helper.Models();
    model.Colors = Helper.Colors();
    model.EngineSizes = Helper.EngineSizes();
    model.Materials = Helper.Materials();
    model.FuelTypes = Helper.FuelTypes();
    model.WheelSizes = Helper.WheelSizes();
    model.BodyTypes = Helper.BodyTypes();
    //more select lists below this
}
```

Then, everything is clean and tidy.